# Extending Django model class (m2m) 2 levels away

Tags: django, django-models

OK I know the title sounds really confusing, but really it's quite simple. Consider this:

```
class A(models.Model):
    field = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class B(models.Model):
    field = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    a_elements = models.ManyToManyField(A)

class C(models.Model):
    field = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    b_element = models.ForeignKey(A)
```

so, now what I want is to extend all instances of A with some other field. for example for every instance of A that is available via B i need an integer associated to it.

is there an easy way of doing this?

EDIT:

I think one can see this as a definition of one-to-many relationship from C to *instances* of A in B, if that makes sense...

Comment: could an instance A be attached to B & C at the same time?

Comment: not really, and that is why i'm having this problem... this is a simplified version of the models. in reality i have a lot more foreign keys (mostly one to many) in class B. hence B is a sort of collection point for everything, like a profile definition. although within all those foreign keys it's only one that needs extending like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to extend all instances of A with another field, add another field.

For your example scenario of needing a field for every A through B, use a through model.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

```
class A(models.Model):
    field = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class B(models.Model):
    field = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    a_elements = models.ManyToManyField(A, through='B_A')

class C(models.Model):
    field = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    b_element = models.ForeignKey(A)


class B_A(models.Model):
    """
    Custom through model for B.a_elements
    """
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
    integer = models.IntegerField()


b = B.objects.latest('id')
ab_elements = B_A.objects.filter(b=b).select_related()
# these are your m2m intermediary model instances, 
# which are essentially A instances with an extra field.

for ab in ab_elemements:
    print ab.a # a element
    print ab.integer # integer associated with this a element.
```

By your question title, I think you're asking a question about C though (which you didn't mention)

Comment: sorry if the question is confusing, i just had a hard time formulating it. but yes, it's about C. B does not need to add extra info, it's the C that needs this extra info.

Comment: So I take it C is uncommon enough that you want to separate the C-B-A data? If you need data between each C - A instance, then your only choice is another m2m field from C - A, some normalized field that stores `b.a_elements.all()` ids and their associated values, or an extra field on `B.a_elements.through`

Comment: yes something like that, although i don't see a way of telling this to Django... only solution that i came up with is: class D, that has this extra field, then from C I do one-to-many to this new class D. class D instances created automatically, when C is initiated (as at that moment I know how many I need). The drawback is that i can't (easily) from A see all related D instances....

Comment: Sounds like your idea would create 2 extra tables. C -> FK D, D -> m2m A. Why not C -> m2m A. That's one extra table. `a_instance.through_model_foreignkey_set.all()` == all A-C m2m models with special integer column. `select_related()` and you don't cost an extra query for accessing C instances.

Comment: I was just hoping to avoid duplicating links, because C already is m2m with A via B. In other words: some of the A instances link to a particular instance of B. That particular instance of B links to an instance of C. So the link between A and C is already there, I just need to add an extra field on each link. Now if I understand what you're saying correctly, I would do another m2m link from C to A (via D that has this extra integer). This sort of duplicates the A-B-C link, but so would any other solution. So I suppose I just need to make sure my code maintains the integrity. Thanks!!